# What does "Sweep out my igloo" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In restaurant scene from *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), during their discussion, columnist J.J. Hunsecker, Senator Harvey Walker and Agent Manny got interrupted by a press agent Sidney:

> J.J. Hunsecker: The day I can't get along without a press agent's
> handouts... I'll close up shop and move to Alaska lock, stock, and
> barrel.
>
> Agent Manny: **Sweep out my igloo**. Here I come.
>
> J.J. Hunsecker: Manny, you rode in here on the senator's shirttails,
> so shut your mouth!

What does "Sweep out my igloo" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J.J. jokes about moving to Alaska, so Manny carries on the joke - "Get my accommodation ready, I'm coming to Alaska too." Of course, people in Alaska don't really live in igloos, it's just a cliché for 'the far North'.